# Gatsby Serverless Function Error: 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, serverless, netlify-function

I've been trying to set up a serverless function for sending emails in my Gatsby website. The function is being hosted, but whenever I try to get it, it tells me that it doesn't exist.

My fetch:

```
const body = {
  name,
  email,
  phone,
  message,
};

fetch(`http://localhost:8000/.netlify/functions/sendMail`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(body),
})
  .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Middleware in `gatsby-config.js`:

```
developMiddleware: (app) => {
  app.use(
    "/.netlify/functions/",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:8000",
      pathRewrite: {
        "/.netlify/functions/": "",
      },
    })
  );
},
```

Function path:

- root

  - functions

    - sendMail

      - node_modules
      - package.json
      - sendMail.js
      - yarn.lock

I think it has something to do with the url I am getting it with in my `fetch()` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `netlify-lambda serve <functions folder>` to compile and serve your functions in development, you need to set your `target` to the port that the `netlify-lambda` listener is bound on, which is `9000` by default. Right now you're redirecting to port `8000`, which appears to be the port your Gatsby app is running on.

So, for example, you want your set up to look more like this:

```js
  // Forward Netlify Function requests to `netlify-lambda` server
  // when the development server is running.
  developMiddleware: app => {
    app.use(
      "/.netlify/functions/",
      proxy({
        target: "http://localhost:9000", // <--- Port that `netlify-lambda` is using
        pathRewrite: {
          "/.netlify/functions/": "",
        },
      })
    )
  },
```